# Empirical application for probability of $h$-deranged permutations

Tags: probability, applications, derangements

## Background

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ distinct items, there are a total of $n!$ permutations of them. A derangement is a permutation in which not a single item is in its 'natural position'. The number of derangements of a collection of $n$ distinct items is given by:

$$!n \triangleq n! \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

Since the set of derangements is an equivalence class within the set of permutations, and $!0 = 0!$, we can believe $!n \leq n!$. Taking $\Omega$ to be the set of permutations, a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ on $\Omega$, and a probability measure $\mathcal{P}(X) \triangleq \frac{\mathcal{C}(X)}{\mathcal{C}(\Omega)}$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is a counting measure on $\Omega$, we have the probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathcal{P})$. With the counting functions mentioned above, the probability of randomly selecting a permutation can be given by:

$$Pr(\text{Derrangement};n) = \frac{!n}{n!} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

By fixing $n-h$ positions to remain in their natural position, leaving $h$ positions to be deranged, the number of $h$-deranged permutations can be given by:

$$\binom{n}{n-h}!h$$

Similar to before, the probability of an $h$-deranged permutation being selected is given by any of the following equal expressions:

$$\frac{\binom{n}{n-h}!h}{n!} = \frac{!h}{h!(n-h)!} = \binom{n}{n-h}\sum_{k=0}^{h}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

With these definitions and expressions we can find that the probability of the $0$-deranged permutation is $\frac{1}{n!}$, the probability of an $h$-deranged permutation with $h \neq 0$ is $1 - \frac{1}{n!}$, and the probability of an $h$-deranged permutation with $h \neq n$ is $1 - \sum_{k=0}^{h}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$.

## Question

Does there exist an empirical application (scientific, economic, engineering, etc) for computing probabilities of $h$-deranged permutations?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Computing probabilities of "$h$-deranged permutations" is useful... *for when you want to know the probabilities of $h$-deranged permutations*.  Do you really need a word problem written that uses this when in the end if you stripped away all of the flavor of the word problem it all boils down to the basic original problem of finding probabilities of your $h$-deranged permutations?

Comment: "*$20$ men walk into a club, each wearing a distinct hat, and the receptionist takes their hats from them when they enter.  When they leave, the receptionist gives them a hat at random from those remaining.  What is the probability that exactly $k$ men get their correct hat back?*"

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for your feedback. I see how you've misunderstood the question. I will try to find an appropriate edit to clarify. In the mean time, I would offer that in the sciences we are not particularly interested in contrived word problems.

Comment: "*You want to test to see if a monkey is successfully learning how to read and associate words with images.  To do this, you have a stack of $n$ cards with words and a stack of $n$ cards with images, each word card uniquely corresponding to an image card.  The monkey is trained to select one card from each stack and if they match are rewarded with a treat.  Regardless of if they match or not, the cards selected are taken away after.  If the monkey selects entirely at random, what is the probability the monkey receives $k$ treats?*"

Comment: "*Contrived word problems*"  One could argue that every word problem is contrived in some fashion.

Comment: @JMoravitz Agreed. I invite you to find a [cheritable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_charity) fashion.